# Diffficulty in understanding some assignments in Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am new to programming, and have started learning linked lists, but I am having serious troubles in understanding what some of the assignments are actually doing in the code.

For example:

```
void moveNode(node** desti, node** source) {
    struct node* newNode = *source;
    assert (newNode != NULL);
    *source = newNode -> next;
    newNode -> next = *desti;
    *desti = newNode;
```

Like in `node* newNode = *source`, `newNode` is a pointer pointing to the value in `source` pointer?

`*source = newNode -> next;` for this, the `source` pointer is getting the address of `newNode`, getting linked with `newNode`?

I am unable to understand these assignments.

PS: This `moveNode` code is for merging two sorted linked lists.

Also, please shed some light on when the address is passed or stored in the above code.

Comment: A) Indentation is important to communicate intent and meaning. B) Don't put spaces before the `;`, that's not normal and it's highly distracting. There's many [popular indentation styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) you should consider adopting to make your code more consistent, understandable, and familiar to others.

Comment: A linked list is a horribly inefficient datastructure on modern CPUs. But, if you insist on it, you should be using `std::list` rather than building your own. In any case, I'd advice to just use a `std::vector` instead - it's likely to be faster for most usecases (regardless of what "big O" may say about list - benchmark it if you don't believe me).

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Actually, I am having a really hard time grasping these concepts.

Comment: C++ is one of the more challenging languages to learn out of the gate not only because of its complexity, but because of how utterly awful many C++ courses are. Don't let that discourage you, though. It looks like you're getting tripped up on pointer mechanics, so it might be worth trying to tackle C first, a language that's a lot simpler in scope, and then build up to C++. What you have here is basically C code anyway which is unfortunately how C++ is taught in a lot of schools.

Comment: IMHO, learning linked lists and pointers is best done with drawings.  Draw the list and the nodes as you walk through the code.

Comment: @tadman I think learning C first isn't really a good idea for the exact same reasons teaching C in C++ is bad. You end up messing with pointers, dynamic memory, and char arrays instead of using standard library containers. If anything, C++ is more simple.

Comment: @FeiXiang I think C++ can be taught properly with modern Standard Library-based approaches where `new` and pointers are brought up near the end of the curriculum, but unfortunately most "C++" courses are fundamentally terrible and take a backwards approach. If that's the case, learning C first helps add important context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code moves a node from the front of the source list to the front of the desti list.

```
void moveNode(node** desti, node** source) {
    struct node* newNode = *source;
    // Now newNode points to the first node of the source list
    assert (newNode != NULL);
    // assert if source is empty
    *source = newNode -> next;
    // Pop first node from source by making it point to the next node
    newNode -> next = *desti;
    // Add newNode to the front of the desti list
    *desti = newNode;
    // Lengthen desti by pointing to the new first node
```

Comment: thankyou for the answer I am still confused like in the first line newNode points to the first node which means link field of newNode will have 1st source node's address and in the third line first node from the source is pointing to which next node? Since newNode->link is equivalent to the link field of the newNode which will store some address.

Comment: Since newNode is the first node of the source list, newNode->next is the second node of the source list.